# Convert nested string list into floats keeping the order

Tags: python, arrays, list, type-conversion

I have a series of nested lists that I have imported from a .csv file, with comma separation and I need to convert the nested list to an array and also convert each element of every sublist into a float.

My nested list looks like this:

```
[[['[-27.19579876 -26.63047926 -25.66265752 -24.66628419 -25.96622205\n -28.30443609 -31.76915607 -38.00372114 -47.35791383 -39.40005965\n -29.22445377 -26.42370679 -28.66477882 -34.30370308 -35.18059249\n -34.46565279 -37.44988995 -39.01483496 -37.37774557 -34.56711077\n -33.19832104 -33.03131686 -34.41439695 -37.37570899 -42.09990677\n -44.07871575 -42.44796064 -44.26494463 -49.32499311 -56.70048713\n -64.66553782 -59.24921176 -54.79892771 -55.26403902 -59.2072573\n -63.22472635 -68.80195015 -75.08662546 -76.91907172 -77.38337998\n -77.63201733 -77.95896847 -78.64834584]'
   '[-1.08386134  0.35004455  0.27842593 -1.94350689 -4.44183424 -4.07447619\n -1.77572529 -0.23410515  0.45280711 -2.23341921 -2.76410909 -3.15466483\n -3.40239693 -3.69140218 -1.79075435  0.6430064   3.24091082  3.31559296\n -0.01170333  0.69596049  1.39120214  2.02807499  3.00311775  4.18844905\n  5.95027894  5.19644159  1.94171193 -0.50207882 -1.7136904  -0.73163291\n  3.19769766  7.31430314  7.34184555  7.62544895  8.32473157  8.58314892\n  8.1814814   6.13480498  5.4934919   5.44513918  5.20248941  5.33109816\n  5.27733676]'
   '[ -8.7461804   -8.00752109  -8.83808412  -9.5394061  -10.56202961\n  -9.91695934  -8.74573382  -6.06317537  -3.36842469  -6.9563696\n  -8.64882906  -9.41769463  -9.34989943  -7.4820141   -6.60575234\n  -6.60480487  -5.72743738  -4.33574933  -6.03119951  -7.1813543\n  -6.87034601  -7.09557771  -8.17130602  -8.05209492  -5.9291385\n  -3.98802667  -4.14947874  -3.3090392   -1.16519149   1.10024417\n   1.4521037   -2.03653649  -3.63826979  -4.33748373  -4.19752051\n  -3.32306985  -1.52347287   0.64845846   1.89777445   2.50546914\n   2.59801871   2.85173201   3.07714712]'
   ...
```

As you can see, It's a nested list with sublists that contain sub-sublists (and so on) that are strings. So, when I try to convert them to arrays and save the values as floats as shown below, I get the following error:

```
nested_list = np.array([nested_list]).astype(np.float)



   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[-27.19579876 -26.63047926 -25.66265752 -24.66628419
 -25.96622205\n -28.30443609 -31.76915607 -38.00372114 -47.35791383 -39.40005965\n -29.22445377
 -26.42370679 -28.66477882 -34.30370308 -35.18059249\n -34.46565279 -37.44988995 -39.01483496
 -37.37774557 -34.56711077\n -33.19832104 -33.03131686 -34.41439695 -37.37570899 -42.09990677\n
 -44.07871575 -42.44796064 -44.26494463 -49.32499311 -56.70048713\n -64.66553782 -59.24921176
 -54.79892771 -55.26403902 -59.2072573\n -63.22472635 -68.80195015 -75.08662546 -76.91907172
 -77.38337998\n -77.63201733 -77.95896847 -78.64834584]'
```

So, as I understand, one whole sub-list is a string, and separating it by spaces or commas will group the values with '[' and '\n' symbols. As I said, my goal is to only access the values so that I can keep the structure of the nested lists, and convert those values to floats to later put them in an array.

The dimensions of the multidimensional arrays in the end are to be ( *sample number/list length*, 16).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: " contain sub-sublists (and so on) that are strings." They aren't sublists. They are strings. Using `csv` to naively serialize this data was a mistake. There are only hackey ways to retrieve the data. You should really fix this fundamental problem, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga any suggestions on how I could properly fix the problem?

Comment: Is length of all your sub lists equal??

Comment: @CutePanda No, it isn't. All have different lengths.

Comment: @JazminCristina What is the depth of nested lists? It is just a big list which contains different sized lists? Or the sub lists also contains sub sub lists?

Comment: @CutePanda the list has the dimensions (186, 16) and every sublist contains the dimensions (*sample number*, 16)

Answer (score 0):

looks like your csv file not formatted properly.
use readlines function, then strip the '\n' part .
may be it works